# Is there a way to optimize this Google Map dot density map algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps

I am creating a dot density map with random distribution to represent the population per county. Right now, essentially what I am doing is taking the maximum latitude and longitude values of a county, picking two random numbers between them, and testing against the bounds of the polygon that outlines the county to see if it falls within it. If it does, I add it to the map and if it doesn't, I go back and try again. This runs many thousands of times so the misses really hurt loading time. I would really like to figure out a way to draw within the bounds rather than pick a random point, test it, and then draw it. I don't even fully understand how my testing algorithm works as I borrowed the code from [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test/2922778#2922778) so I am in over my head at this point, but I thought it might be a fun challenge for some of you.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
function addMarkers() {
        var loc = "Resources/Counties.json";

        $.getJSON(loc, function (data) {
            $.each(data.features, function (key, val) {

                var xArray = []; //
                var yArray = []; //

                var coords = [];
                var latlng;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var polygon;

                $.each(val.geometry.coordinates[0], function (i, item) {
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item[1], item[0]);
                    xArray.push(item[0]); //
                    yArray.push(item[1]); //
                    coords.push(latlng);
                    bounds.extend(latlng);
                });

                var nverts = xArray.length; //
                var maxX = Math.max.apply(null, xArray);  //
                var maxY = Math.max.apply(null, yArray);  //
                var minX = Math.min.apply(null, xArray);  //
                var minY = Math.min.apply(null, yArray);  //

                polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: coords,
                    strokeColor: "#000000",
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWeight: 01,
                    fillColor: "#cccccc",
                    fillOpacity: .5
                });

                polygon.setMap(map);

                var i = 1;
                while( i < populations[val.properties.Name] / 10000){
                    var testX = Math.random() * (maxX - minX) + minX; //
                    var testY = Math.random() * (maxY - minY) + minY; //

                    if(pnpoly(nverts, xArray, yArray, testX, testY) == 1){  //
                        var mlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(testY, testX); //
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: mlatlng, icon: "Resources/dot.png", map: map });   //
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    function pnpoly(nvert, vertx, verty, testx, testy)
    {
       var i, j, c = 0;
       for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) 
       {
          if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
          (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
          {
             c = !c;
          }
       }
      return c;
    }
```

Comment: There is a [google.maps.Polygon "containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)" function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) in the "geometry" library.

Comment: Thanks, I did start using that instead of the pnpoly(), however I'm really looking for something that will help me avoid creating random points and testing it against the polygon altogether.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is create a color map (colors are unique and derived from feature index) of the features to test random (bbox constrained) coordinates against.  I know if the coordinate is within the feature by its color in the color map.  This test is a O(1) operation, where as the code you posted is O(n).  My dot density map of china counties performs fine.  I started with this guy's code example:

https://gist.github.com/awoodruff/94dc6fc7038eba690f43